# Rails - How to add a BLOB column using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, blob, rails-postgresql

I need to create a BLOB column to store some text content.

I have read somewhere that I need to do the following:

```
class AddVersionCommentToMetaData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :meta_data, :version_comment, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :meta_data, :version_comment
  end
end
```

However, it gives the following error message:

> PGError: ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "bytea" LINE 1:
>   ..."meta_data" ADD COLUMN "version_comment_extended" bytea(1048...
>                                                                ^ : ALTER
>   TABLE "meta_data" ADD COLUMN "version_comment_extended"
>   bytea(10485760)

Any idea?

Please note that I am using PostgreSQL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The migration seems to be correct except the down part. It should be:

```
class AddVersionCommentToMetaData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :meta_data, :version_comment, :binary, :limit => 10.megabyte
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :meta_data, :version_comment
  end
end
```

double check for typos. And what version of rails are you using? It works well in rails 3.0.7.

Comment: Actually I made the typo when copy pasting on StackOverflow (the real column name is version_comment_extended but I made it shorter on purpose to improve the readability. I am using Rails 3.0.5.